# Samsung tablet keyboard gone

Tags: samsung, tablet

Its my mums tablet she recently downloaded the new update on her tablet and since it downloaded the keyboard has gone and all she can do is speak to the mic but its not working properly and its too hard for her to use and now we cant connect it to the internet either.  any help please???

Comment: may you please specify which tablet,what version she WAS running and is now running?

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings -> My Device Tab -> Language and input and check if the settings are correct. If the default keyboard is set properly and still not working, try to install another keyboard application like SwiftKey and make it default keyboard.